# How to click on a specific coordinates of an element

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I need click on a specific coordinates of a element with **watir-webdriver**. With **selemium-webdriver** it will be looks like:

```
@driver.action.move_to(element, 30, 0).click.perform
```

But how do it with **watir**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you will have to access the selenium-webdriver driver directly (assuming `browser` is your watir-webdriver browser):

```
browser.driver
```

To get the underlining selenium-webdriver element for a watir-webdriver element, use `wd` (assuming `element` is your watir-webdriver element you want to click):

```
element.wd
```

Putting it all together, you would do:

```
browser.driver.action.move_to(element.wd, 30, 0).click.perform
```

Comment: thanks, i tried it, but it's don't work for IE 9 in my case. For **IE** works well `fire_events`. Is it possible to call in some fire_event item coordinates? I work with the modified button on similarity [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example11.html), and in my case `element.send_keys(:down)` does not work

Comment: For IE9 are you using watir-webdriver or watir-classic?

Comment: watir-webdriver 0.6.1. I do it with remote on a virtual machine

Comment: Since it works in Firefox, your issue sounds like a bug in the InternetExplorerDriver, which you could log at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver.