# is it possible to send a click/pointer event to an svg to specific x/y coordinates?

Tags: svg, watir

I have webpage with an interactive svg scatter plot. How do similate a click event of a given point using watir.

I have already tried sending a basic click event to the svg.

`browser.elements(css: 'g.trace scatter g.points').click`

But it only selected the point in the middle of the graph.

Assuming I have the x/y coordinates, how do I send an event to the svg to select any point on the scatter graph?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/14688892/1200545 answer your question?

Comment: yes, it does. Thank you